# How to get the new height of a scaled Shape in Java

Tags: java, shapes, affinetransform

I am scalling a shape for a specific point as follows :

```
                AffineTransform t = shape.getAffineTransform();

                AffineTransform translatAffine =AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-cx, -cy);
                AffineTransform scaleAffine= AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(sx,sy);
                scaleAffine.concatenate(translatAffine); 
                translatAffine = scaleAffine;

                scaleAffine =AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(cx, cy);
                scaleAffine.concatenate(translatAffine);
                translatAffine = scaleAffine;                   

                scaleAffine= new AffineTransform(t);
                translatAffine.concatenate(scaleAffine); 
                shape.setAffineTransform(translatAffine);
```

When I try to get the new height with `shape.getHeight()`, I get the initial height

Comment: @trashgod: Yes, but the Shape interface doesn't seem to have a getTransform, setAffineTransform, or getHeight methods, so the example isn't making sense.

Comment: :) I agree with your example, @trashgod.  I was just wondering what class the OP was declaring his shape variable to be.  It looks like it's behaving as a comgination of Graphics2D with altered method names plus a Rectangle.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @Atreys, The shape object is as you describe it, it has also an affineTransform attribut and two methods : public AffineTransform getAffineTransform() {
  return new AffineTransform(t);
 }


 /**
  * @param t
  */
 public void setAffineTransform(AffineTransform newT) {
  t = newT;
  notifyObservers();
 }

Comment: To make code easier to read, update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work a round by getting the affineTransform and calculating the new height. I added the follwing line to the code above

```
System.out.println("The new height :"+ shape.getHeight() *  shape.getAffineTransform().getScaleX());
```